# How to make alphabetical sorting using ractive on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

Here i want help to aplhabetical sorting on load

here i am getting json data using ractive each method in jsp:

This is my jsp code :

{{#each conditionsList:i}} // this is my json iterative object
        
            
            {{healthConditionType}}

This is my js code :

```
R_PersonList = new Ractive({
    el: "#health-information-details-container",
    template: "#health-information-details-template",
    data: {
        personList: personJson,
        allergiesList: personAllergiesJson,
        conditionsList: personConditionsJson,
    },
    sort: function (array, column) {
        array = array.slice(); // clone, so we don't modify the underlying data
        return array.sort( function (a, b) {
            return a[column] < b[column] ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example was somewhat... inconclusive, so I made you a simple table example of sorting a list alphabetally by column using "your" sorting function.

With this you should hopefully get a little bit further in your tries.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2kvrjus/)

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script id="template" type="text/html">
     <p>Click a column header to sort alphabetically by that property</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th on-click='sort:Name'>Name</th>
        <th on-click='sort:Food'>Favorite food</th>
        </tr>
        {{#Animals}}
        <tr>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Food}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/Animals}}
    </table>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var ract = new Ractive({
    template: "#template",
    el: "#output",
    data: {
        Animals: [{
            Name: "Rabbit",
            Food: "Cables"
        }, {
            Name: "Crocodile",
            Food: "Humans"
        }, {
            Name: "Owl",
            Food: "Dunno"
        }, {
            Name: "Cat",
            Food: "Wool"
        }, {
            Name: "Shark",
            Food: "Seals"
        }, {
            Name: "Developers",
            Food: "Caffeine"
        }]
    }
});
ract.on("sort", function(event, column) {
    array = this.get("Animals");
    this.set("Animals", array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[column] < b[column] ? -1 : 1;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Hi here i want to sort json object onload uisng div

Comment: How to do sorting in onload?

Comment: Not in click function

Comment: In that case you would need to modify the array before rendering it. F.ex in _init_ event ([lifecycle events](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/lifecycle-events)). 
That being said. If this is data you are generating yourself, you should do the initially wanted sorting on the server instead of the client. 

[Updated JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz50fero/)